# Are ancillary qubits necessary to represent a syndrome measurement in the circuit model?

Tags: error-correction, quantum-circuit, stabilizer-code

From my understanding, in QEC with stabiliser codes, one can use the operator formalism and state to perform a measurement over a space which is orthogonal to the code space. This allows to not destroy the code information.

However when stepping to the circuit model representation, there are some ancillary qubits come in play. The reason for this I suppose is for practical implementation.

My question is: Can we represent a syndrome measurement in the circuit model without the use of ancillas?

Answer (score 5):

You can create circuits that perform the stabilizer measurements without using ancilla qubits. For example, you can take a data-qubit-only surface code and do a pattern of CNOT gates that temporarily reduces the 4-body stabilizers to observables on single data qubits and then measures those data qubits.

The problem is that, when you do this, you often find that it makes the threshold worse or reduces your code distance, because the way you're performing the stabilizer measurements spreads noise around in a worse way than using ancillae.

In the case of the surface code, it turns out that if you look closely at the state halfway through the stabilizer measurement cycle, you find it's the state of a rotated surface code of twice the size! This means a data-qubit-only surface code circuit is really just a normal surface code circuit but started halfway through the measurement cycle. You tried to only use data qubits, and ended up with a measurement-qubit-using rotated surface code of half the size.

Here's a rotated surface code with its double-sized halfway-through-measurement-cycle unrotated surface code superimposed over it:

[image]

And here's something to help you remember:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Auxiliary qubits are employed because no realistic quantum processor supports four$^1$-body measurements. If we did have quantum hardware that supported four-body measurements then we could implement the surface code without auxiliary qubits.

In order to represent such a surface code in the circuit model we need to extend the set of elementary operations to include four-body measurements. For example, we could represent such a measurement as a box spanning four qubits. The box leaves the four qubits in the appropriate post-measurement state and yields one classical bit of syndrome information which we can draw as a double line going off to the side. The box would also need a label, such as $XXXX$, to indicate the observable it measures.

Note that modifying the set of elementary operations changes the syndrome extraction circuits and requires a new error model to express our assumptions about how the new operations fail. This in turn alters the consequences and probabilities of various possible physical errors and affects the details of the relationship between the physical and logical error rates including the threshold probability.

---

<sup>$^1$ We also need two- and three-body measurements around boundaries.</sup>